# How to align button on stackpanel in windows phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have added two buttons in stackpanel and set alignment as shown in the code

```
<StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
<Button Content="Button" Height="64" Name="button1" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Button Content="Button" Height="64" Name="button2" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</StackPanel>
```

but this doesn't match with my requirement. I want it to be like shown in image below.

[image]

So how can i do this?

Comment: is that Windows Phone 7? looks like iphone :-)

Comment: its of iphone only. that's the requirement

Comment: Indent mark and code by 4 spaces so that it shows up correctly in your question.  Consider reading the Markdown documentaion that is displayed on the right hand side when editing a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<Grid
    Width="480">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button
        Width="200"
        Content="Clear" />

    <Button
        Grid.Column="1"
        Width="200"
        Content="Options"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        />

</Grid>
```

**UPDATE: Due to popular demand, here is a grid without the fixed width or the columns.**

```
<Grid>

    <Button
        Width="150"
        Content="Clear"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        />

    <Button
        Width="150"
        Content="Options"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        />

</Grid>
```

Comment: Are the two columns really necessary?

Comment: with this i get the desired out but my gui get disturbed is there any other way to do this. Can i do this without playing with grid.

Comment: @rubyraj: What do yo mean by "disturbed"?? `Grid` is the right tool for the job unless you have some other requirement you haven't told us about?

Comment: @SteveChadbourne: Do you need to set the `Grid` width explicitly? Also, repeating what @AnthonyWJones asked, I don't think the 2 `ColumnDefinitions` are needed either.

Comment: No, probably don't need to set the grid width and may well be able to do it without 2 columns - just quickly put up some code I used that works. Always interested to see other ways of achieving layout if someone else wants to put up some alternative xaml.